# 403 error when using MediaWiki REST API to `compare` revisions

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

***NOTE:*** *The bug in the API has now been fixed, and this issue no longer arises.*

---

I'm building a simple tool for myself that will display the difference between revisions on Wikipedia using (by sending a request to the **WikiMedia REST API** as described in the API's docs here: [Reference#Compare revisions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API/Reference#Compare_revisions)).

Here is an example of code which retrieves the JSON I want:

```js
const url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/revision/1157633768/compare/1157658266";
let json = await fetch(url).then(resp=>{ return resp.json(); }); 
console.log(json)
```

**This code works** in a local Node REPL, or likewise it works if I point my browser to <en.wikipedia.org>, and use the in-browser console to run the code.  Likewise, I can simply `curl` that url and get the data printed in my terminal.

**However**, I get a 403 error if I use that same code in my site (or, equivalently, if I use the in-browser console to run the code when pointed at a site other than wikipedia).  Here's the error I get:

> `GET https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/revision/1157633768/compare/1157658266 403`
>
> ```js
> {error: 'rest-cross-origin-anon-write', httpCode: 403, httpReason: 'Forbidden'}
> ```

The error title seems to indicate I'm being forbidden access since I'm trying to write from a cross-origin site, but the request I'm doing is a simple read-only, request isn't it? According to the reference page linked above Error 403 is returned when "*Revision not publicly accessible*".  However, it's clearly publicly accessible since I can access it from any browser or `curl` without authentication.

[Note, if I make any other requests using this API, like getting the details for a single revision (as in docs here: [Reference#Get_revision](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API/Reference#Get_revision)) with url `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/revision/1157633768/bare`, I do not get this error.  It's only when requesting the `{from}/compare/{to}` route.]

I've tried adding `?origin=*` to the url
as the site for the [MediaWiki Action API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) suggests [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests). I know this is a different API, but it was still worth a shot.

I don't know much about cross-origin requests, but I feel like this should be simple.  I am not trying to do anything that requires authentication.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. `MediaWiki\Rest\Handler\CompareHandler` inherits the default Handler's needsWriteAccess() -> true.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not literate enough in these matters to understand.  Where do you think the bug resides (so I can maybe direct my question there)?

Comment: The REST compare handler inside mediawiki core isn't declaring it doesn't need write access, hence the error. I don't think there's any good reason why this is the way it is, I'd recommend reporting this as a bug to https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I raised a bug report there: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T347721

Comment: I believe it was wise to report the bug, but have you considered using a server-side proxy as a temporary solution? This approach could also provide additional caching options for optimizing requests in the future if you ever wanted to do so.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan that sounds like a good idea.  But I was working with writing a simple client-side JS site.  I don't actually know how to implement a server-side proxy and pass information back and forth from the client to make these requests.  Something to learn...

Comment: BTW, this patch should fix this issue https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/mediawiki/core/+/962696

Comment: The patch has been deployed and I can no longer reproduce the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug originates from the "Origin" header (no pun intended), which the browser may or may not add to all XMLHttpRequests. Unfortunately the "Origin" header is in the list of [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), so it can't be altered nor deleted.

To work around that bug, I'd go with what @PCDSandwichMan suggested in the comments and (temporarily) go through a server side proxy. If your server supports PHP and "allow_url_fopen" is set to true, you could add the following **proxy.php** to your web root:

```
<?php
readfile('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1' . $_GET['path']);
```

and change your JS code to

```
const url = "/proxy.php?path=" + encodeURIComponent("/revision/1157633768/compare/1157658266");
const json =await fetch(url).then(resp=>{ return resp.json(); }); 
console.log(json);
```

If your web host does not "allow_url_fopen" but has the PHP cURL module enabled, change the contents of **proxy.php** to:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1' . $_GET['path']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I've tested both options successfully.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, I don't know what I'm doing well enough to test it myself.  I just have been editing JS/jQuery and HTML files locally, and opening the HTML in my browser.  I learned how to use nodeJS with express to make a proxy server, but now it seems maybe I should have learnt about PHP instead?  All I would like to accomplish is to have a user (me) type in the API route (like `/revision/1157633768/compare/1157658266`) and get back the JSON data as an object I can manipulate in JS and display back to the user.  I can do this already with calls that don't give 403 errors.

Comment: As mentioned by my fellow peers in the comments: The 403 response seems indeed to be a bug in the REST API that needs to be fixed, so it's not your fault and there's nothing really you could do about it other than wait or try the workaround. If you need that proxy now and for your local project only, DM me on Twitter (or X or whatever it is called today) and I'll provide a link to one of my servers for you to use.